# Wall thickness and line count in Cura, are they redundant, or do they multiply?

Tags: ultimaker-cura

I'm experimenting with larger nozzles and large objects. I thought I had left the default wall count at 3 and that's why the print was turning out much sturdier and much heavier than a smaller nozzle, even though it took 1/3 - 1/2 as long to print it.

Well, I have a 1 mm nozzle, `wall thickness` set to 2 mm, and `wall line count` at 2.  I expected that `wall thickness` was to be multiplied by `wall line count` to arrive at the final wall width.  However, I don't think that's the case, the two values seem to be interrelated and redundant.  [This forum post](https://community.ultimaker.com/topic/25607-cura-360-understanding-wall-thickness/) from a few years ago tries to say as much.  I now think that `wall thickness` is extrusion width (`line width`?) multiplied by `wall line count`.

The problem that I saw that made me dig into this, is that the `wall thickness` is set to double the line width, leading me to believe that I'm getting 2 walls of double-width walls, which means 4 mm thick walls.  I don't think it's doing that, but I may have confused myself in the process. Looking at the line view, I think the walls are 2 mm.

How are these two variables related?

[This question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/7425/help-to-reconcile-nozzle-diameter-deposited-line-width-and-wall-thickness-in-c) is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

> I expected that `Wall Thickness` was to be multiplied by `Wall Line Count` to arrive at the final wall width.

No, the `Wall Thickness` is the width of the complete wall, not of a single extrusion line, that is `Wall Line Width` which is a sub option of the `Line Width` property. Note that `Wall Line Width` itself is split up into `Outer Wall Line Width` and `Inner Wall(s) Line Width`

`Wall Thickness` is "`Line Width`" multiplied by the `Wall Line Count`

Note the `Wall Thickness` is calculated when you change the `Line Width`/`Wall Line Width` or greyed out, further more, when you set the wall width to a specified width, the amount of lines are calculated.

Comment: In general, Cura has a lot of these kind of "derived settings" where it's somewhat confusing which one is the actual setting and which is an awkward indirect way of setting it.